# React async data (object) getting corrupted while assigned to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to React and having some issue with data binding. It seems like when I assign an object to another object to another object it gets corrupted and I cannot target using it's key.  I have fiddle set up at http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/uv7scjb6/.

Thanks in advance

```
function getMyData(){
    return {name: 'foo', age: 20};
}

var Header = React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function () {
            return {data:null};
        },

        loadData: function () {
             this.setState({data: getMyData()});
        },

        componentDidMount: function () {
            this.loadData();
        },


        // Render the component
        render: function() {

            return(
                <div>
                    Welcome, {this.state.data.name}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

React.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: `return {data:null};` --- so say again how are you going to get `name` from the `null`?

Comment: My understanding was when the componentDidMount executes, it calls the new loadData function. The loadData will make a async call. Once the data is loaded, isn't it suppose to update the data: null to data: getMyData() result? What am I missing here.

Comment: It is supposed (if your code didn't crash), but how about accessing `name` from `null` which happens initially?

Comment: Hmm... good  questions. I know why it's failing. I need restructure the initial state.  Thank you much for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the initial state, the `state.data` is still null and `render()` fails.
The component never gets mounted and the data never gets loaded.

You can update the render method to return a different `<div>` if the data is null or you should provide a different initial state.

```
render: function() {
  if(!this.date.data) {
    return(<div>Loading...</div>);
  }
  return(<div>Welcome, {this.state.data.name}</div>);
}
```